# Output insert and table values when doing insert into

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm inserting into a table in MS SQL Server 2008 (it's rather a copy of values from the same table) and want to get the output values for the insert. I want to get the id value of the select statement (t.id in the example below), the INSERTED.id works just fine

```
create table tmp.tbl_inserted (fromId int, toId int)

INSERT INTO mytable (name)
OUTPUT t.id, INSERTED.id INTO tmp.tbl_inserted
SELECT t.name FROM mytable t
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you're really asking here. What's the relevance of `tmp.tbl_inserted`? You declare it and don't use it. Where exactly is `t.id` supposed to be coming from?

Comment: Typo, changed now. t.id is supposed to come from the table mytable

Comment: Ah OK, makes more sense :) And I see Damien beat me to it. Glad it works!

Comment: This is exactly my situation. I never thought I'd manage to find an existing question for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it directly from an [`INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177564.aspx):

> *from_table_name*
>
> Is a column prefix that specifies a table included in the FROM clause of a DELETE, UPDATE, or MERGE statement that is used to specify the rows to update or delete.

Note that `INSERT` isn't mentioned.

What you have to do instead is cheat and use a `MERGE`:

```
MERGE INTO mytable m
USING (name,id FROM mytable) t ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (name) VALUES (t.name)
OUTPUT t.id, INSERTED.id INTO tmp.SizeCurveGroup_inserted
;
```

Comment: I can't believe I actually found this question and answer. It's exactly the answer I needed.